# How do I know if a portable HDD is in use and will hot-plug hurt it?

Tags: hard-disk

The concern started with whether a portable HDD will be physically damaged or degraded if unplugged when the disk is still spinning. I understand that I can force unmount the device on Linux. However, let us suppose I am using the `smartctl` command running a self test on the drive. Now, the drive is not mounted, so the system suggests it is safe to be unplugged. So if one forget there is still a test running, one may unplug it accidentally while the disk is still spinning.

Two questions:

1. Is there a command that stops all reading/writing activities on the portable HDD and let the head park properly?
2. Will unplug while spinning physically damge or degrade the HDD in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a command that stops all reading/writing activities on the
>   portable HDD and let the head park properly?

`# shutdown now`

> Will unplug while spinning physically damge or degrade the HDD in use?

It can, [if the read/write head scratches the drive platter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_crash). Usually, it takes a good jolt to cause that to happen, which is why [some modern include sensors to protect against this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer#Consumer_electronics). It's also why a lot of portable drives are SSDs, which don't have moving components that can fail (like disc platters).

Data corruption from unexpected power loss in the middle of a write operation can be prevented by using the `df` command to make sure the drive isn't mounted (use `umount /path/to/mountpoint` to unmount), and `fuser -vam /dev/sdb*` (replacing `/dev/sdb*` with the block device assigned to the drive in question) to confirm nothing else is using the relevant block device. If the drive isn't mounted or in use, you can safely unplug it.

Comment: But doesn't shutdown also cut the power supply? Is it possible that the power is cut while IO is still on ongoing by the command shutdown by the shutdown command?

Comment: Yes, it does. [No, that is not possible](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122667/63783).

Comment: Specifically, http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/drivers/base/core.c#L1946