# What is exactly the procedure that makes reboot possible in Linux?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, bios

I've been wondering how a linux pc (e.g. Debian) is restarted.

To an "outsider" a pc seems to be completely shut down just before it is started again; is it so?

I had a look at the [source code of reboot command](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c) but didn't catch much.

Could someone care to explain?

I assume the BIOS is the one responsible for rebooting the computer, given that BIOS is always on, especially in that second when the computer seems switched off. However, I don't know for sure.

There could be a similar question about any other OS (Windows, macOS and whatnot) but I guess this is not the right forum. Nevertheless, I'd be curious to know whether other OS's handle reboot similarly to Linux.

---

**Edit**: My question is specifically about how exactly the transition from shutting down to starting again happens (without pressing a button), which is only (kind of?) mentioned in question [How does the system shutdown of a linux kernel work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally) in the following passage of the first answer:

> Finally go to rest in some machine-dependent way by calling machine_restart, machine_halt or machine_power_off.

Could someone elaborate at least on that? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the system shutdown of a linux kernel work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally)

Comment: Sorry, I searched but couldn't find the topic. I'll read that!

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.13.5/drivers/acpi/reboot.c

Comment: I believe [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/294681/how-does-a-computer-restart-itself) is the closest one to mine and I find it very interesting indeed. I'd like to hear a linux specific answer to it though.