# implementation of system shutdown in reboot vs. systemd-logind

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, shutdown, reboot

This question is motivated by curiosity, and because I've been unable to find a clear answer on my own.

I have read [this answer explaining how the kernel shuts down the system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122667/286615). Overall, it seems clear to me. Reviewing the code for `reboot.c` in LXR, the [`kernel_power_off` function in reboot.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/reboot.c#L176) piqued my curiosity. Unfortunately, LXR seems to stumble when locating the *machine-dependent code* for [`machine_power_off`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.13.5/+code=machine_power_off), and it's not clear to me what this function does, or how it does it.

QUESTION: Is the *function definition* for `machine_power_off` typically based on some binary blob (proprietary firmware perhaps?) unique to a specific class of machines - or a manufacturer - or is it typically written in Assembler or even C?

Now fast-forward from the April 2014 to July 2021 - the present. The April 2014 answer made sense to me, but there have been many changes since this answer was prepared: Numerous revisions to the kernel, and `systemd` has become a default part of many/most Linux distros.

It's my understanding that `halt`/`shutdown` is now handled by the `systemd` ***login*** manager(?!): `systemd-logind.service`. Reviewing `man logind.conf` and `man systemd-logind.service` reveals the `HandlePowerKey=`,  `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=` options, and the associated `poweroff` action - these option names suggest similarities with `reboot.c`, but things are clearly different. Looking further upstream at implementation suggested [the D-Bus interface of systemd-logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.login1.html) plays a significant role in system shutdown now. At this point, I'm struggling to *"connect the dots"* between `reboot.c` and `systemd-logind.service`.

In the meantime, [my distro seemingly has retained the `reboot.c` code](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.10.y/arch/arm/kernel/reboot.c). Assuming that the code is being maintained only because it's still used on my `systemd`-based OS leads me to my other question:

QUESTION: Do `systemd`-based options for powering off a system ultimately end by executing `reboot.c`? If not, what is the role of `reboot.c`?